# Android 4.0 Unified UI Framework

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

According to the [Android 4.0 Platform Highlights](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-4.0-highlights.html), there is now a Unified UI Framework that allows, from my understanding, developers to develop one application (resulting in one APK) that can be used on both smartphones and tablets.

What does this really mean for developers *in practice*? Can anyone point to any code samples that illustrate this framework?

**EDIT**: To clarify, what I'm really asking is what are the means to make an application dynamically "look good" on both a smartphone and tablet without having to create another APK, and does the new Unified UI Framework provide the means to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Google beat us to the punch with their new [Android Training](https://developer.android.com/training/index.html) website, specifically [Designing For Multiple Screens](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html), [Implementing Adaptative UI Flows](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/adaptui.html), and [Creating Multiple APKs for Different Screen Sizes](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-apks/screensize.html). While it doesn't specifically address the Unified UI Framework at 4.0, it lays it out nicely.

Answer (score 1):

What this means is that Action Bar and Fragments(+ bunch of other framework components) can be used on Phones as well as Tablets.

Comment: I understand this, but what are the means to make it "look good" on both a smartphone and tablet respectively?

Comment: They key is to have different layouts for phones and tablets give the screen real estate available. You could have multiple fragments shown together in a tablet and one leading to another in a phone.